# React-query: typescript and abstract useMutations?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a small app with several kinds of data similar with each other. For example data for labels and statuses. And so the apis are similar too.

Now with `react-query`, I'm writing many repetitive mutations. All the mutations (add, update, delete) have same structure:

```
export const useUpdateLabel = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(updateLabel, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("labels");
      console.log(`Updated`);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && console.error(error);
    },
  });
};
```

I'm using custom hooks to make the code cleaner, but is there any way to reduce the repetitive codes?

I can do something like:

```
export const useCustomMutation = (func, key) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(func, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(key);
      console.log(`Updated`);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && console.error(error);
    },
  });
};
```

but have no idea how to make the types right.

Answer (score 0):

this should work nicely:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient, QueryKey } from 'react-query'

export const useCustomMutation = <TArguments, TResult>(func: (args: TArguments) => Promise<TResult>, key: QueryKey) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(func, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(key);
      console.log(`Updated`);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && console.error(error);
    },
  });
};
```

[link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCyyYEMbAQB2ANChgIrLpQCeAwgDbDpExlU20DS6tcAXzgAzKBBBwA5FHS4AxjAC0AR2p1JAWABQ29AA9IsOHOKp4adPTQxx2PAWJwAvHAA8AFQCCUAObIQrDCoZO4ASuioyIwwAHwAFMLIRHIAXHBxuL6oaV6%20-oGoAJTOMXAACmIgwBge4ZHRMWQA1nxpnHS8tMVOpQjacMam8KpcTCxszuTo7QzMgXGFANz9cDIwyFBEU3b4hEQJSXJkfVoDA8QAyshychHZ6d29K2dwI3RjgQB0wEQAbrjMAAm%20GmahYqDiLS6y1OL0GRFQEEY6E%20jAgPjiAAMAKpgYEwdCAzFLZ6CEik4gAUSgYigaTiNFpj0QpIGYDEt1QqE%20rF%20nwAcgB5AAilIA%20pT%20QA1OAAQicLgAROyIIDrg4iIq4AAybXwxHInk06AM41QEmwgYCcmwgQWgSLIA)